# Is there a random access container type that accepts a prefilled & preallocated buffer?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, containers

I'm about to write something myself since I didn't find what I was looking for, but figured I should ask the crowd before diving in.

- Is there a boost or stl random access container type that allows passing in of prefilled buffer?

The imaginary(?) container type would operate something like this:

```
  const int blobSize = unpackBlobSize( msg );
  int *     blob     = unpackBlobData( msg );

  SpecialVector<int> mySpecialIntVector( blob, blobSize );
```

Basically I'm interfacing an old library with c-style raw pointers-to-buffers, but would like to use C++ style container semantics without requiring a copy step. What I would hope to have is std::vector plus preallocated & prefilled buffer constructor and, minus resize.

Libeigen has this sort of functionality with their Eigen::Map which allows things like the following:

```
  int array[9];
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) 
      array[i] = i;
  stl::cout << Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix3i>(array) << stl::endl;
```

Anyone know of a boost or stl template that covers these constraints?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the library, but I believe Boost.Range probably has something you can use.  As I understand, it provides a few thin wrappers that make pairs of iterators look like containers

Comment: @Dennis that seems like it might be a real solution. Checking into it.

Comment: @Dennis, do you want to make this into an answer or shall I?

Comment: Feel free, I haven't actually looked deep enough into it to give a working example.

Comment: I don't see why there should be. `std::vector` tries to emulate the standard array as close as possible plus implicit reallocation. If you ask for "minus resize", what are you left with? If you want to use std **algorithms** you can pass pointers as iterators. Can you give an example of why you would want a vector API on a fixed buffer? Having said that I think that in `std::string` case this would be very useful.

Comment: @davka, See the example in my question. Basically accessing old APIs in a safe(er) C++/STL way.

Comment: that's my point, I **don't** see an example. What's in `vector`'s API (if not automatic resize) that you lack? "safe(er) C++/STL way" are just words, sorry. You can run out of vector's boundaries as happily as you can with a built-in array. The only safer thing about vector is implicit memory management, but you gave this up. Pointers are just a kind of (built-in) iterators, it's ok to use them as such as long as you don't manage you memory by yourself. STL is just a tool, not a talisman against bad stuff :)

Comment: @davka: I'm not sure if you're just trying to make a point, or really don't understand what I'm going for. But, I'm trying to do 2 things: 1) pass the size with the allocation 2) provide/enforce iterator/container semantics so that everything is done in the same way (and so fewer mistakes are made) "*...implicit memory management, but you gave this up*" re-read my question. I didn't give it up; it wasn't an option. I'm dealing with old code that I can't change.

Comment: I do understand **what** you're asking for, I keep saying that I don't see **why** you want this. "provide/enforce iterator/container semantics": vector **is** the array semantics **plus** memory management. If you (are forced to) give up memory menagement, you're back to the array. My point is: array **is** a container, pointer **is** an iterator, they are not re-defined in STL just because the language provides them. They are perfectly ok to use re iterator/container semantics, in fact vector mimics it. Do you believe that `v.begin()` is better than `&a[0]`? That's just a notation.

Comment: And the only (or at least main) reason for Boost solution of "pseudo" containers, IMHO, is to be able to use them in (poorly designed) API calls that take container instead of a pair of iterators.

Comment: "*Do you believe that v.begin() is better than &a[0]?*" Yes.

Comment: @davka let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1913/discussion-between-catskul-and-davka)

Comment: "*... in (poorly designed) API calls*" I disagree. `setPoints( pointVector )` instead of `setPoints( pointVector.begin(), pointVector.end() )` make a difference for readability which I assert, matters. It would also be bad practice to pass around two pieces of information like a pointer to an allocation and it's size, (or end iterator) separately. Passing a range or container solves that problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going from Dennis Zickenfoose's comment, I looked up Boost.range seems to offer the perfect solution:

```
  #include <boost/range.hpp>
  #include <boost/foreach.hpp>
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
    const int blobSize = 100;
    int blob[blobSize];

    for( int i = 0; i < blobSize; ++i )
      blob[i] = i;

    boost::iterator_range<int*> blobPsudoContainer( blob, blob + blobSize );

    BOOST_FOREACH( int & i, blobPsudoContainer )
      i = i + 1;

    std::cout << "Size is:" << blobPsudoContainer.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "value at 0 is:" << blobPsudoContainer[0] << "\n";
    return 0;
  }
```

Thanks Dennis! : )

Comment: Nice. I don't think it would have occurred to me to use `boost::range` for this particular purpose. I had always thought of it only for representing a subset of a container - applying it to a C array to turn the array into a `container` just wouldn't have entered my mind.

Comment: Now I'm getting greedy... I'm wondering if I can rig it to automatically convert `std` container types so that I can just have all of my templated function signatures take `boost.range` types and cover all bases for free : )

Comment: @Catskul: Ranges aren't types; they're _concepts_. `boost::iterator_range` is a type that implements a range concept; it happens to be defined by two user-supplied iterators. You can implement types that satisfy the range concept too. All of the standard containers also just so happen to satisfy the range concept.

Comment: @Nicol, *"Ranges aren't types; they're concepts"* Yeah, I get that. If I didn't we wouldn't be having this conversation ;) If you'd prefer me to be more verbose, I'm trying to say that I think I can probably produce templatized functions that instantiate boost ranges from std container types automatically so I handle std::container types, and ranges together without specializing.

Comment: @Catskul: But you can't instantiate ranges from anything, because ranges are concepts and concepts can't be instantiated. Also, Boost.Range already includes many template algorithms that handle range types. They also have delayed evaluation functionality, so you can compose multiple algorithms into one in an efficient way. And standard containers already fit the range criteria, so any template function that accepts a range concept will accept a standard container.

Comment: @Catskul : Nicol didn't strike me as condescending at all. I think it's just you ;-]

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing like you want, this is just a shortcoming of the language. If you were satisfied with having the allocator statically guess a good expected maximum element count, you could just embed a normal C array inside an allocator and defer to it as long as possible; this is usually called an auto buffer.

---

Old Answer:

All of the standard library containers allow you to specify an allocator. You can make a buffer allocator.

Comment: Very interesting idea. I would still be left with the resize issue though.

Comment: @Catskul It will use your custom allocator when resizing.

Comment: It looks like he wants the provided buffer to already contain initialized values; a standard library container will assume the allocator returns uninitialized memory, and overwrite the existing data.

Comment: I was about to write it but now we should clarify: @Cat: Do you want to pass in the buffer, or just assume some sort of expected static buffer. Why are you dynamically allocating your buffer anyway?

Comment: The assumption is that the buffer has already been created, and is being passed out of some old c-style api. The buffer would be static in the sense that its size/location would not change once passed in. I'll clarify my example.

Comment: @Catskul: Then perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just start using your buffer then? What does sticking it in `std::vector<>` and then not using `std::vector` features gain?

Comment: @Catskul: I see. A `std::vector` + allocator isn't going to work then. `std::vector` wants raw memory from the allocator, and constructs values into that memory. You already have type-specific memory, and just need to fill it in. Is that correct?

Comment: @Catskul: I see. Then indeed, you'll need to write your own class. There's no pre-existing "shell" class. This is just a shortcoming of C++: arrays are most often indistinguishable from pointers, they should have been their own type.

Comment: Sorry that was me. I meant to just undo my upvote (which I had added when I thought the allocator might work) and hit down instead. It's locked in now so I can't undo it : / sorry.  Boost.Range does effectively provide exactly what I was looking for though btw.

Comment: @Cat: No worries. I don't care about the rep so much as I like to know what I get wrong. So don't worry about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd post the custom solution I ended up using for posterity and in case anyone was curious or had any comments. Please forgive the tight formatting; It was to get rid of the horizontal scroll.

Do let me know in the comment section if you use this. I'd be curious to hear if it was useful to anyone else.

We'll need the following headers:

```
 #include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
 #include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
 #include <vector>
```

A helper to hook onto an existing refcounted object

```
 template<typename RefCountedTypeT>
 struct RefCountLinkFunctor
 {
   public:
     RefCountLinkFunctor( const RefCountedTypeT & ptr ) 
       : m_ptr(ptr) 
     { 
       &RefCountedTypeT::use_count; // try to check if refcounted
      } 

      template<typename T> void operator()(T*) {}

   protected:
     RefCountedTypeT m_ptr;
 };
```

And then:

```
 template< typename DataT >
 class DataRange : public boost::iterator_range< DataT * >
 {
 public:
   typedef boost::iterator_range< DataT * >    ParentType;
   typedef DataRange< DataT >                  OwnType;
   typedef DataT                               DataType;
   typedef boost::iterator_range< DataType * > Range;
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< OwnType >        Ptr;
   typedef std::vector<DataType>               DataVector;
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<DataVector>       DataVectorPtr;

   static Ptr allocateShared( std::size_t size )
   {
     typedef boost::shared_array<DataType>         DataSharedArray;
     typedef RefCountLinkFunctor<DataSharedArray>  Deleter;

     DataSharedArray   dataArray( new DataType[size] );
     Deleter           deleter( dataArray );

     DataT * begin = dataArray.get();
     DataT * end   = begin + size;

     return Ptr( new OwnType(begin, end), deleter);
   }

   template< typename RefCountedT >
   static Ptr 
   makeShared( DataType * begin, DataType * end, const RefCountedT & refObj )
   {
     RefCountLinkFunctor< RefCountedT >  deleter( refObj );
     return Ptr( new OwnType(begin, end), deleter );
   }

   template< typename RefCountedT, typename InDataT >
   static Ptr 
   makeShared( DataVector & data, const RefCountedT & refObj )
   {
     RefCountLinkFunctor< RefCountedT >  deleter( refObj );

     DataType * begin = &data.front();
     DataType * end   = begin + data.size();

     return makeShared( begin, end, deleter );
   }

   static Ptr makeShared( const DataVectorPtr & data )
   {
     typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<DataType> > InputVectorPtr;

     RefCountLinkFunctor< InputVectorPtr >  deleter( data );

     DataType * begin = &data->front();
     DataType * end   = begin + data->size();

     return makeShared( begin, end, deleter );
   }

 protected:
     DataRange( DataType * begin, DataType * end ) : ParentType( begin, end ){}

};
```